# In Line graph, Why x-axis date format is not coming proper?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have done application using Extjs 4.1. I have plotted line graph, in this x-axis date format is not coming proper. I have defined fromdate, todate and date format, but duplicating December month, Feb month is not coming. line is plotting proper. for more reference have attached images. Can any body tell me how to resolve this issue?. Great appropriated. Thank you.

**Code is here:** 
[image: Date is not coming proper]

```
 {
        type:'Time',
        step: [Ext.Date.MONTH,1] ,
        position:'bottom',
        fields:['Month'],
        fromDate: new Date('12/1/12'),
        toDate: new Date('6/1/13'),
        grid: true,
        dateFormat: 'M Y',
        constrain: true,   
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to change the label orientation to have it displayed verticaly, thus giving more space to display intermediate labels.

You can add a section 'label' do this:

```
label: {
    rotate: {degrees: 270}
},
```